# Можно ли открыть строку с html кодом во внешнем браузере со своего приложения?

Tags: android, kotlin

Вот попробовал по совету чат гпт так:

```
    var content2 = "<html>\n" +
                    "  <head>\n" +
                    "    <title>Моя страница</title>\n" +
                    "  </head>\n" +
                    "  <body>\n" +
                    "    <h1>Привет, мир!</h1>\n" +
                    "    <p>Это моя первая веб-страница.</p>\n" +
                    "  </body>\n" +
                    "</html>";
 val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + content2))
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
 startActivity(intent)
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<html>
      <head>
```

Comment: Смешно. Ну спроси у чатгпт как эту ошибку исправить.

Comment: Не существует контракта на такое действие. Большинство браузеров даже на локальный html-файл не откликаются - только на сетевые ссылки.

Comment: Хотя есть вариант для тех, кто знает толк... Локальный сервер прямо в приложении. Браузеру посылаем ссылку с локальным адресом, он стучится на наш сервер, мы отдаём ему контент.

Comment: Я думал сохранить хтмл в файл и потом открыть этот локальный файл в браузере. Но это геморойно

Answer (score 2):

ChatGPT нахватался думаю отсюда:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37448361/5479247

Только он не понял или не сказал что это по сути хак Chrome браузера образца 2016 года и скорее всего это дверь давно прикрыта.